# Repeated Measures ANOVA - ezANOVA fails

Tags: r, anova

I have data from a psychology experiment in which there is a control and an experimental group. Both groups are tested on reaction times (RTs) for locating where a dot appears on a screen (left/right). Before the dot appears, the participants are presented with two images, one on the left and one on the right. The images can be happy, sad, or neutral. The measures are repeated at three different points in time (T0, T1 and T2):

```
     Emotion    Location     Time Group    RT     Score.D
1     Sad       Incongruent   T0    XP     625   22.83693
2     Happy     Congruent     T1    CTRL   783   22.83693
3     Sad       Congruent     T2    XP     578   22.83693
4     Happy     Incongruent   T0    XP     780   22.83693
5     Sad       Incongruent   T2    CTRL   566   22.83693
6     Happy     Congruent     T1    XP     535   22.83693
```

Here is a subset of my data that can be directly imported in R:

```
structure(list(Emotion = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Happy", 
"Sad"), class = "factor"), Location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Congruent", "Incongruent"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("T0", 
    "T1", "T2"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CTRL", "XP"), class = "factor"), 
    RT = c(625L, 783L, 578L, 780L, 566L, 535L), Score.D = c(22.83693, 
    22.83693, 22.83693, 22.83693, 22.83693, 22.83693)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My supervisor told me to conduct a repeated measures ANOVA with the treatment type (control/experimental) as between-group factor, the D score as an independent variable and the three points in time as the within-group  variable.

I am confused as to how I should achieve this in R. Here is my attempt :

```
Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted$Group <- factor(Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted$Group)
Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted$Time <- factor(Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted$Time)
Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted$Emotion <- factor(Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted$Emotion)
rANOVA.BA.ech1 <- with(data = Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted, aov(Score.D ~ Time*Emotion + Error(Group/(Time*Emotion))))
summary(rANOVA.BA.ech1)
```

This works, but I cannot compute Mauchly's sphericity test on this, which I would very much like to do.
The package `ez` allows for a rANOVA together with Mauchly's test. Here is the code I tried :

```
ezANOVA(Incong.Cong.XP.CTRL.T0T1T2.formatted, 
        dv = .(Score.D), 
        wid = .(generated_uid),
        within = .(Time,Emotion), 
        between = .(Group), type = 1)
```

But I get this error message :

> One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.

Yet there are no `NA` cells in the data...

What's wrong here ?

Comment: Take a look at this and related questions(if you haven't already): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370381/simple-repeated-measures-anova-in-r

Comment: @NelsonGon : Thank you, I have edited the OP with my progress based on the link you gave. Not sure I've nailed it, though.

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please?  (showing just a small subset of your data is useful, but doesn't allow us to reproduce the problem)

Comment: and ... did you run `ezDesign()`? (Is your data at all *unbalanced*, e.g. are there subjects who weren't observed at all three time points?)

Comment: @BenBolker : I will create an MRE, and the data is indeed unbalanced. Yet balancing the design does not change this error message : " One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data."
At the moment I am in doubt about the structure of the data and the analysis I need to conduct. In reality, I want to check if the difference between reaction time means in each subgroup is significant. 
For instance, in the control group at time T0 for sad stimuli, is the difference between mean incongruent and mean congruent reaction times significant ?